# how to correctly initialize a std::vector with type of a struct which contains a std::vector of std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector

Here is a mini-example of my code, how to correctly initialize member pool_ in the constructor.

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

namespace b {

class A;
typedef void (A::*Func) (void);

struct c {
  Func fun;
  int num;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
};

class A {
 public:
  A() {
    pool_ = {{&A::func1, 1, }, {&A::func2, 2, }}; // how to initialize?
  }
 private:
  std::vector<c> pool_;
  void func1(void) { std::cout << "func1\n"; };
  void func2(void) { std::cout << "func2\n"; };
  void CreateThread(c& pool) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pool.num; ++i) {
      pool.threads.push_back(std::thread(pool.fun, this));
    }
  }
};

} // namespace b

int main() {
  b::A a;
  return 0;
}
```

Platform: Ubuntu 14.04 with g++ 4.8.4

compile command:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 test.cc -lpthread -o test
```

The major error message is:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::thread::thread(std::thread&)’
```

I know it is because copy construction and assignment of std::thread is not allowed. But I tried other ways and failed.

Comment: Can you explain what your intent is, for initializing a vector of threads in this manner. It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Please edit your question, and explain what you are attempting to accomplish, here.

Comment: What is **a** in this code ?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want to start a bunch of threads with each member function. I have modified mini-example to add **CreateThread** function so that intention is clear.

Comment: @ArifBurhan I just simplify the code to show the error. So **a** is unimportant.

Comment: Your CreateThread() is already push_back()ing into the std::thread vector, so I see no reason to explicitly initialize the vector. Additionally, func1 and func2 are class methods. You can't "start a bunch of threads" with a class method. You need an instance of the class in order to invoke a class method. This is not the same as passing "this" as a parameter to the class method. You don't invoke class methods this way. I think you should try, first, a simpler way of starting threads. Once you understand the proper way to create and join threads, then you can move on to more complicated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps to solving this elegantly:

1. provide a constructor for c that does 'the right thing'

---

```
struct c {
    c(Func fun, int num, std::vector<std::thread> threads = {})
    : fun(fun)
    , num(num)
    , threads(std::move(threads))
    {}

    Func fun;
    int num;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
};
```

2. Then neatly emplace your objects into `pool_`

   ```
   A()
   {
       pool_.emplace_back(&A::func1, 1);
       pool_.emplace_back(&A::func2, 2);
   }
   ```

Comment: Step 1 is sort of optional. `pool_.push_back({&A::func1, 1});` isn't too bad.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for your clean solution.